# Is it true that $\emptyset\notin\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I've been having a hard time understanding why $\emptyset\notin\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$. Why isn't it an element in that set? Also why is $\{\emptyset\}\in\{\emptyset\}$ true? I know that $\{0\}\notin\{0\}$ so why is that one true and this false?

Determine whether these statements are true or false.

1. $\emptyset\in\{\emptyset\}$
2. $\emptyset\in\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$
3. $\{\emptyset\}\in\{\emptyset\}$
4. $\{\emptyset\}\in\{\{\emptyset\}\}$
5. $\{\emptyset\}\subset\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$
6. $\{\{\emptyset\}\}\subset\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$
7. $\{\{\emptyset\}\}\subset\{\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset\}\}$

Comment: Can you provide more context? To me it seems the other way around, i.e. $\emptyset \in \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ but $\{\emptyset\} \not\in \{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: I believe so too, the answers given were wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's move through each statement one by one.

- $\emptyset\in\{\emptyset\}$

This must be true, as the elements in $\{\emptyset\}$ are everything in between in braces, namely $\emptyset$.

- $\emptyset\in\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$

This is also true, for the same reason. The elements of $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ are $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$.

- $\{\emptyset\}\in\{\emptyset\}$

This is false. The element in $\{\emptyset\}$ is just $\emptyset$, and $\emptyset\ne\{\emptyset\}$.

- $\{\emptyset\}\in\{\{\emptyset\}\}$

This is true. The element in $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ is $\{\emptyset\}$, so $\{\emptyset\}$ is in $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$.

- $\{\emptyset\}\subset\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$

This is true. The statement is asking whether or not all of the element in the set on the left are also *all* elements of the set on the right. Since the element in $\{\emptyset\}$ is $\emptyset$, and $\emptyset\in\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$, it's true!

- $\{\{\emptyset\}\}\subset\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$

This is true. Again, we want to know if $\{\emptyset\}\in\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$, since $\{\emptyset\}$ is the only element in the set $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$. Because $\{\emptyset\}$ is in $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$, this implies that $\{\{\emptyset\}\}\subset\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$.

- $\{\{\emptyset\}\}\subset\{\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset\}\}$

This one is a little tricky. We should know that sets cannot contain duplicates, so $\{1,1,2,2,3\}=\{1,2,3\}$. In this example, that means that the question is actually asking if $\{\{\emptyset\}\}\subset\{\{\emptyset\}\}$. Since $\{\{\emptyset\}\}=\{\{\emptyset\}\}$, this is false, since $\subset$ implies *proper* containment, that is, that the two sets are not equal.

For these questions, it can be helpful to rewrite the questions with different elements. For example, let $\emptyset = 0$ and $\{\emptyset\}=1$. Then $\{\emptyset\}\subset\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ becomes $\{0\}\subset\{0,1\}$.

Comment: This was extremely helpful, thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

It is true that $\emptyset \in \{ \emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$. It is false that $\{ \emptyset \} \in \{ \emptyset \}$. You're right to have been suspicious of both those results.

Comment: Do you mind checking if the answers  to the picture attached is a)T b)T c)F d)T e)T f)F g)F I'm not sure about the last two but I know I can't be trusting the answers given